# Using external .class files in java. Using Eclipse as IDE

Tags: java, class, import, external

I think this is a recurring question on this website, but I haven't found an answer that satisfies me.

Basically, I have a few java .class files I want to unit test. I did copy them in the bin folder of my project outside eclipse and refreshed the folder in eclipse. Still, it seems I can't use thoses classes, in other words I can't write code like.

> MyExternalClass myExtC = new MyExternalClass();

Trying to import the package didn't work neither.

The files where copied at bin\lab\blackBox\

What am I doing wrong here.

EDIT: I have also tried to use the Add External Class Folder, but I had the same errors

Comment: it should work out of the box. Just create a simple eclipse project and run unit tests from within eclipse

Comment: My problem is that I get the "Cannot resolve as type" when trying to use my external classes and "Cannot resolve import" when trying to import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the .class files are arranged according to the package structure.

e.g. When the Java runtime loads `foo.bar.MyExternalClass`, it looks for a file `foo/bar/MyExternal.class` on the classpath. So, the external class folder you add in Eclipse should contain the directory `foo`, which should contain the subdirectory `bar`, which should contain `MyExternalClass.class`.

Comment: That solved my problem AND I also created a folder "output" at the root of my project containing the full path of my classes like you just said and did "Add Class Folder" in the Build Path. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of class files then it is quite possible they declare themselves to be in a certain package (i.e. folder hierarchy) and Eclipse expects to find them there. If the package structure does not match there will be class import issues. If you do know what this structure is you can pack your class files up into jar and take it from there.